# AWS SES: API rate limits on calling SendEmail

Tags: amazon-ses

I plan to send personalized emails to multiple recipients via AWS SES.

Amazon recommends [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/manage-sending-quotas.html) to call multiple times the `SendEmail` method, once for every recipient, instead of just one single call including all recipients at once. However, I'm afraid to hit some API rate limit when calling this method multiple times as they suggest.

They also state [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/quotas.html) that:

> All actions (except for SendEmail, SendRawEmail, and SendTemplatedEmail) are throttled at one request per second.

without specifying the actual limit for the above-mentioned methods, which I haven't been able to find somewhere else.

Does anyone know what is the actual rate limit when calling `SendEmail`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve this information from the AWS SES dashboard or by using the [GetSendQuota](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_GetSendQuota.html) API.

The `GetSendQuota` returns the following:

- Number of emails you have sent during the past 24 hours
- Sending quota for the current 24-hour period
- Maximum send rate

Maximum send rate determines the no. of mails you can send per second.

You can apply for increasing the quota (i.e; both no. of emails you are allowed to send per second and max. send rate).
More info on the same [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/manage-sending-quotas-request-increase.html).

Attaching the screenshot of SES dashboard for reference.

[image: AWS SES dashboard]